# Manipulating a file with nested tags and key-value pairs

Tags: python, file, parsing, text

I have a need to work with configuration files that use nested HTML-style tags of key-value pairs using equals signs.

I'd like a Python approach that would allow me to read such files, add, delete or modify sections, and write the updated file.

The files look like:

```
<tag1>
key1=value1
key2=value2

<tag2>
key3=value3
</tag2>

<tag2>
key3=value four

</tag2>

</tag1>
```

So its not quite a HTML or XML file, and not a Windows INI file either.  There are no spaces surrounding the equals signs, there are a few random blank lines in the files that seem to be ignored and values in the key-value pairs don't use quote marks and may have embedded spaces.

I could not find a definition or name for this exact file structure but I found it hard to focus the search so I may have missed something obvious.

Is this a recognized standard file structure?  If so what is it called?

I'd appreciate any pointers on what libraries can be coerced into working with this structure and maybe some examples if they are not readily available in the docco.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output format

Comment: The format Is just ordinary xml. The text content of each tag can be parsed using simple string manipulation (i.e. `splitlines()` and `partition('=')`).

Comment: @Shiva: Thanks!  Output format is the same as the input.  I should have clarified that the file I am manipulating is a quite large (5k - 10k line) file used by a third-party application and I want to systematically add, remove an alter elements.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Thanks!  It hadn't occurred to me to use an XML parser and then work with the key=value pairs as just text.  Obvious now you point it out.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For keeping configuration files , you can use the `configparser` module in python. This makes it very easy to read config information in your app.

For a config file like this :-

```
[installation]
library=%(prefix)s/lib
include=%(prefix)s/include
bin=%(prefix)s/bin
prefix=/usr/local

[debug]
log_errors=true
show_warnings=False

[server]
port: 8080
nworkers: 32
pid-file=/tmp/spam.pid
root=/www/root
```

> You can read this configuration file like this shown below :

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
cfg = ConfigParser()

cfg.read('config.ini')
['config.ini']

cfg.sections()
['installation', 'debug', 'server']

cfg.get('installation','library')

'/usr/local/lib'

cfg.getboolean('debug','log_errors')
True

cfg.getint('server','port')
8080

cfg.getint('server','nworkers')
32

print(cfg.get('server','signature'))
```

If you wanna go with only that html kind of configuration , checkout `xml.etree` module . It offers a wide range of functions .

Comment: Thanks!  The file format is something I'm stuck with - I am manipulating the config/database file used by a third-party application rather than adding config storage to a program I am in control of.  `xml.etree` looks like what I need, especially given @ekhumoro's observation above..

Comment: if the answer was helpful , pls upvote and tick mark it :)